# Node.js write after end error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code which was working in node v0.10.28 perfectly.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.path === "/" || req.path === "/index.html") {
            var token = req.cookies && req.cookies.token ? req.cookies.token : undefined;
            if (token) {
                next();
            } else {
                console.log("Request url is....................." + req.url);
                console.log("time while redirecting to login...." + new Date());
                console.log("userAgents........" + req.headers['user-agent']);
                try { 
                    res.redirect('/login');
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log("error....." + error.message);
                }
            }
        } else {
            next();
        }
    });
```

But after switching to node v0.12.7, this is giving error.

```
Error: write after end 
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (_http_outgoing.js:413:15) 
at ServerResponse.res.write (/node_modules/compression/index.js:87:17) 
at ServerResponse.res.end (/node_modules/compression/index.js:104:14) 
at ServerResponse.redirect (/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:846:8) 
at Http.js:11:21 at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
```

This error is coming continuously 3 times and then repeat after every hour.
Here are some of my consoles.

```
Request url is...................../
Time while redirecting to login....Thu Aug 06 2015 15:58:18 GMT+0000 (UTC)
UserAgents........Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.67 Safari/537.36
Uncaught Err>>>>>>Error: write after end

Request url is...................../
Time while redirecting to login....Thu Aug 06 2015 15:58:18 GMT+0000 (UTC)
UserAgents........Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.67 Safari/537.36
Uncaught Err>>>>>>Error: write after end

Request url is...................../
Time while redirecting to login....Thu Aug 06 2015 15:58:31 GMT+0000 (UTC)
UserAgents........Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.67 Safari/537.36
Uncaught Err>>>>>>Error: write after end
```

This error is not caught in catch block and becoming uncaught error.

I will really appreciate any hints for how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: Is it possible that some other function is writing to the output buffer after you call `res.redirect();`? By calling `res.redirect` The webserver ends the request and sends out its response (in this case a redirect header), but apparently some code is trying write to that response after it has been sent.

Comment: To clarify further. The error is not actually in the function you posted in your question, but is raised somewhere else.

Comment: Do you have any other middleware that could possibly serve on requests `/` and `/index.html`? If yes, they might be trying to write something. Also, your try block would obviously not catch errors thrown by `redirect`.

Comment: @Hless I have stopped the flow as soon as i have called res.redirect('/login')  and i am not calling next() function after this. Even stack trace is showing that error is originating from this line.

Comment: @Салман No, i do not have any other middleware that could serve these requests.